# Mismatch npm? Why does 'yo generator-jhipster' not show oracle in my database options?

Tags: npm, yeoman, jhipster, yeoman-generator-angular, yo

The latest version of jHipster gives different options than the one being displayed in my command prompt. I am wondering why am I missing some things like the oracle database option?

Does anyone have any ideas? Doing npm list generator-jhipster shows that I in fact DO have the current latest version.

This is what I should see:
[What I should see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZs87.jpg)

Versus what I actually see:
https://twitter.com/BuilderDeviser/status/694251531261050882

Doing an npm list -g --depth=0 :

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
+-- bower@1.7.7
+-- capslink@0.0.0
+-- generator-jhipster@2.27.0
+-- grunt-cli@0.1.13
+-- gulp@3.9.0
+-- npm@3.6.0
+-- reinstall@1.1.0
+-- semver@5.1.0
+-- strongloop@6.0.0
`-- yo@1.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.... i did a drive search for 'generator-jhipster' and windows found all folders of that name.

I looked at each path and found that generator-jhipster way back from 2.7 was still hanging around in zip format. I definitely don't need that anymore. I ended up trashing any old instances of generator-jhipster and any cache/temp locations.

I reinstalled forcing npm to target 2.27 by doing 'npm install -g generator-jhipster@2.27'

Now I have the current and latest version of jhipster runnning!